# MySQL wont let me add column

Tags: mysql, alter-table

This should be a really simple process but for whatever reason, I am unable to add a column to an MySQL table. Here's my syntax:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE game_licenses ADD lifetime VARCHAR(255) AFTER expire_date";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    echo "it failed";
}
else {
    echo "success";
}
```

I've tried multiple little changes like adding COLUMN to the query after ADD. There are no MySQL errors but finishes the script and echos "it failed".

The error is:

> ALTER command denied to user 'webuser'@'localhost'

Is it possible to lock a table from being altered?

Comment: What says mysql_error()?

Comment: How do you know there are no errors? `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: I added echo mysql_error() and got this: ALTER command denied to user 'webuser'@'localhost' for table 'game_licenses'

Comment: Well, there you have it, the user you are connected to the server with is not allowed to execute alter queries on that table.

Comment: pretty clear, you don't have permissions for user "webuser", enter with an admin user and give him permissions to alter the table "game_licenses"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have the privileges to do so.

Make sure you have the `alter` privilege on that table.

Have the superuser (root) execute the following:

```
GRANT ALTER ON dbname.game_licences TO `webuser`@`localhost`
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html.

P.S. Are you sure you want normal users to be able to issue `alter` statements?
Better option may be to issue the alter statement as root, or even better to make an admin account that has full rights on the database, but not full rights on any other database.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. Thanks to everyone for your responses.